Jmeter how to measure latency in microseconds
We are running load test for http and https request between client and server by using jmeter command line.
jmeter -n -t /tmp/jmeter/https_test.jmx -f -S /tmp/jmeter/jmeter.properties -j /tmp/jmeter/jmeter-http-50.log -l /tmp/jmeter/result-http-50.csv -JProtocol=http -JPort=80 -Jip_address=10.2.1.4 -Jthread_num=50 -Jloop_count=20000

Now the default measure unit for latency report is milliseconds. Like the following
`timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
`1714506750052,79,HTTPs Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,859,111,3,3,https://10.2.1.4/,79,0,74
1714506750135,2,HTTPs Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,859,111,3,3,https://10.2.1.4/,2,0,0``
is there anyway to measure the latency with microseconds?
I found from web that I need to update jmeter.properties to allow measurements be in microseconds. But I am not able to find in the jmeter user manual. Can someone please help me?

If you take a look at i.e. Aggregate Report listener documentation:

Times are in milliseconds.

See Analyzing JMeter Test Results Using JMeter Aggregate Report Listener article to see what are the metrics and what do they mean.
As of JMeter 5.6.3 connect time, elapsed time and latency are measured with milliseconds precision and there is no easy way of switching it to microseconds, you can try requesting an enhancement and the more people who will vote for this feature more likely it will be implemented.

If you are running on a virtual machine then the float on the virtual system clock will destroy any integrity in such measurements.   In short, what happens is that the clock in the virtual machine floats relative to the machine clock.  Periodically the virtual machine clock "syncs" with the physical machine clock resulting in clock jump as the degraded clock becomes one with the physical machine clock.  This happens in the span of a few microseconds but depending upon how busy your system is you will find jumps of up to a few seconds.
This manifests itself in higher averages, maximums, standard deviations, 90th percentiles, ...,. on virtual machines versus physical ones.   This not only impacts load generators, impacting test repeatability, but also on virtual machines running web/app servers collecting time-taken values in their logs, timing collected by deep diagnostic tools that measure the difference between beginning and ending timestamps (to the millisecond), and timestamps for "when" something occured captured by a database record.
If you have any hope to capture to the level you desire with high integrity then you begin with an all physical hardware definition.  No virtual machines beyond the Java or .Net variants running inside of the operating system.
